# Having a function `t.test()` take multiple variables inputted to it in R

Tags: r, function

I was wondering if there is a way to avoid using `t.test()` 3 times for comparing 3 variables `x1`, `x2`, and `x3` and instead using `t.test()` one time to take any two variables at a time inputted to it?

For example, for: `x1 = rnorm(20) ; x2 = rnorm(20) ; x3 = rnorm(20)`, I'm now using: `t.test(x1, x2)   ;  t.test(x1, x3) ;  t.test(x2, x3)` but could I just use `t.test()` one time?

**Here is what I tried with no success:**

```
t.test(cbind(x1, x2, x3))
```

Comment: For that very reason `anova` is used.

Comment: Correct. `t.test()` works for a pair of variables and you would have to perform three tests propagating error in checking your hypothesis thrice. `anova` avoids this by comparing the hypothesis for multiple variables together. If you want to do it once using t.test(), it's simply not possible.

Comment: @TUSHAr, I fully understand that! But my question is a programming question here! Just want to know can I make `t.test()` function in `R` do what I want from a Programming standpoint?

Comment: You can use `pairwise.t.test` and adjust the pvalue with a correction method, possibly `bonferroni`

Comment: @rnorouzian please check my answer. Does this address your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

similar to your question on `cor` just now, here is the syntax for handling pairwise calculation:

```
set.seed(21L)
x1 <- rnorm(20); x2 <- rnorm(20); x3 <- rnorm(20)

pcor <- function(...) {
    combn(list(...), 
        2,  
        function(y) cor(y[[1]], y[[2]]),
        simplify=FALSE)
}
pcor(x1, x2, x3)

pttest <- function(...) {
    combn(list(...), 
        2,  
        function(a) t.test(x=a[[1]], y=a[[2]]) #change this to whatever your want
        simplify=FALSE)
}
pttest(x1, x2, x3)
```

Comment: check out `lower.tri` if you want a similar output

Comment: whatever you have done can be written as: `combn(data.frame(x1,x2,x3),2,function(x)t.test(x[1],x[2]),F)`

Answer (score 2):

We can use `pairwise.t.test`

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
data(airquality)
airquality %>% 
    mutate(Month = factor(Month, labels = month.abb[5:9])) %>% 
    summarise(pval = list(pairwise.t.test(Ozone, Month, p.adj = "bonf")$p.value)) %>%
    pull(pval) %>%
    extract2(1)
#             May        Jun         Jul         Aug
#Jun 1.0000000000         NA          NA          NA
#Jul 0.0002931151 0.10225483          NA          NA
#Aug 0.0001949061 0.08312222 1.000000000          NA
#Sep 1.0000000000 1.00000000 0.006969712 0.004847635
```

---

Using the OP's example

```
pairwise.t.test(c(x1, x2, x3), rep(paste0("x", 1:3), each = 20), p.adj = "bonf")

#     Pairwise comparisons using t tests with pooled SD 

#data:  c(x1, x2, x3) and rep(paste0("x", 1:3), each = 20) 

#     x1    x2    
# x2 0.486 -    
# x3 1.000 0.095
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
x1 <- rnorm(20) 
x2 <- rnorm(20) 
x3 <- rnorm(20)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to randomly use any of the variable try this:

```
s = sample(x = c("x1","x2","x3"),size = 2,replace = F)
t.test(eval(parse(text=s[1])),eval(parse(text=s[2])))
```

Answer (score 0):

By using pairwise t-test the alpha value must be adjusted. Bonferroni correction is often used in agriculture, Holm sometime in medicine. Without such correcting one have more significant differences than it should be.